# cannot get data from form after submit in Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuelidate

I have this project in laravel with vue js and this registration form that uses vuelidate to validate all fields. the problem is that when I submit it I could not get the inputted data from the the fields. I think it has to do with the vuelidate library that I use. if there's any mistake im willing to learn from it. I'm new to vue so im not that familiar with it. thank you for your help

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center gap-3">
                <div>
                    <TextInput
                        :class="{
                            'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                                v$.firstName.$error,
                        }"
                        placeholder="Given Name"
                        id="firstName"
                        type="text"
                        class="mt-1 block w-full"
                        v-model="state.firstName"
                        autofocus
                        autocomplete="given-name"
                        @blur="v$.firstName.$touch()"
                        @keyup.tab="v$.firstName.$touch()"
                    />
                    <InputError
                        class="mt-2"
                        v-if="v$.firstName.$error"
                        :message="v$.firstName.$errors[0].$message"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <TextInput
                        :class="{
                            'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                                v$.lastName.$error,
                        }"
                        placeholder="Family Name"
                        id="lastName"
                        type="text"
                        class="mt-1 block w-full"
                        v-model="state.lastName"
                        autocomplete="family-name"
                        @blur="v$.lastName.$touch()"
                        @keyup.tab="v$.lastName.$touch()"
                    />
                    <InputError
                        class="mt-2"
                        v-if="v$.lastName.$error"
                        :message="v$.lastName.$errors[0].$message"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3">
                <TextInput
                    :class="{
                        'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                            v$.email.$error,
                    }"
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    v-model="state.email"
                    autocomplete="username"
                    @blur="v$.email.$touch()"
                    @keyup.tab="v$.email.$touch()"
                />

                <InputError
                    v-if="v$.email.$error"
                    class="mt-2"
                    :message="v$.email.$errors[0].$message"
                />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3">
                <TextInput
                    :class="{
                        'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                            v$.password.$error,
                    }"
                    v-model="state.password"
                    id="password"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    autocomplete="new-password"
                    placeholder="New Password"
                    type="password"
                    @blur="v$.password.$touch()"
                    @keyup.tab="v$.password.$touch()"
                />

                <InputError
                    v-if="v$.password.$error"
                    class="mt-2"
                    :message="v$.password.$errors[0].$message"
                />
            </div>

            <InputLabel value="Gender" class="mt-3" />
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center gap-3">
                <RadioInput
                    :class="{
                        'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                            v$.gender.$error,
                    }"
                    :modelValue="state.gender"
                    @update:modelValue="state.gender = $event"
                    id="maleRadio"
                    class="mt-1 w-full bg-white/70"
                    name="gender"
                    value="male"
                >
                    Male
                </RadioInput>

                <RadioInput
                    :modelValue="state.gender"
                    @update:modelValue="state.gender = $event"
                    id="femaleRadio"
                    class="mt-1 w-full bg-white/70"
                    name="gender"
                    value="female"
                    :class="{
                        'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                            v$.gender.$error,
                    }"
                >
                    Female
                </RadioInput>
            </div>
            <InputError
                v-if="v$.gender.$error"
                class="mt-2"
                :message="v$.gender.$errors[0].$message"
            />

            <InputLabel value="Section" class="mt-3" />
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
                <div>
                    <select
                        v-model="state.sectionId"
                        :class="{
                            'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                                v$.sectionId.$error,
                        }"
                        id="sectionId"
                        @change="getDivision($event)"
                        @blur="v$.sectionId.$touch()"
                        @keyup.tab="v$.sectionId.$touch()"
                        class="mt-1 bg-white/70 w-full bg-white border-gray-300 focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-green-500 rounded-md py-2.5"
                    >
                        <option selected disabled>Choose a section</option>
                        <option :value="section.id" v-for="section in sections">
                            {{ section.section_name }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <InputError
                        v-if="v$.sectionId.$error"
                        class="mt-2"
                        :message="v$.sectionId.$errors[0].$message"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <select
                        :class="{
                            'bg-red-50 border border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-700':
                                v$.divisionId.$error,
                        }"
                        v-model="state.divisionId"
                        :disabled="isDisabled"
                        id="division"
                        @blur="v$.divisionId.$touch()"
                        @keyup.tab="v$.divisionId.$touch()"
                        class="mt-1 bg-white/70 w-full bg-white border-gray-300 focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-green-500 rounded-md py-2.5"
                    >
                        <option selected disabled>Choose a division</option>
                        <option
                            :value="division.id"
                            v-for="division in divisions"
                        >
                            {{ division.division_name }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <InputError
                        v-if="v$.divisionId.$error"
                        class="mt-2"
                        :message="v$.divisionId.$errors[0].$message"
                    />
                </div>

                
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-end mt-4">
                <PrimaryButton
                    class="w-60 mt-3"
                    :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }"
                    :disabled="form.processing"
                >
                    Create Account
                </PrimaryButton>
            </div>
        </form>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    sections: {
        type: Array,
    },
});

const isDisabled = ref([true]);
const sections = props.sections;
const divisions = ref([]);

const form = useForm({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    gender: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    divisionId: null,
});

const rules = computed(() => {
    return {
        firstName: { required, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
        lastName: { required, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
        gender: { required, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
        email: { required, email, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
        password: {
            required,
            $lazy: true,
            minLength: minLength(8),
            $autoDirty: true,
        },
        sectionId: { required, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
        divisionId: { required, $lazy: true, $autoDirty: true },
    };
});

const state = reactive({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    gender: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    sectionId: null,
    divisionId: null,
});

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state);

const getDivision = async (event) => {
    // Do something when the select value changes
    const selectedId = event.target.value;
    console.log("Selected id:", selectedId);
    try {
        if (selectedId == "null") {
            isDisabled.value = true;
            return;
        }
        const response = await axios.get("/get_divisions/" + selectedId);
        divisions.value = response.data;
        isDisabled.value = false;
    } catch (error) {
        isDisabled.value = true;
        console.error("Error fetching divisions:", error);
    }
};

const submit = async () => {
    v$.value.$touch();
    if (!v$.value.$error) {
        try {
            await state.post(route("register"));
            state.reset("password", "password_confirmation");
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle error if form submission fails
            console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please fill all fields");
    }
};
</script>
```

I tried changing the v-model back to form.firstName but using wont be validate the fields